# Get Canvas Context using force:canvasApp after authorization

Tags: lightning-aura-components, canvas-app

I'm trying to see some of the authentication tokens returned by the client after successfully authorizing my `force:canvasApp` aura component.

Any attempt to use `Sfdc.canvas` within lightning aura components has proven to be unsuccessful so far.